# Why my Google cloud run instance don't connect to my Google Cloud sql DataBase?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I already create an instance in google cloud run, is an api in .net 6. But it doesn't connect to my database in google cloud.

This is my method that create the conection String instance.

`

```cs
 public static MySqlConnectionStringBuilder ConectionStringBuilder()
        {
            var connectionString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None,
                Server = "/cloudsql/proyect:region:instance",
                UserID = "user",
                Password = "password",
                Database = "dataBase",
                ConnectionProtocol = MySqlConnectionProtocol.UnixSocket
            };
            connectionString.Pooling = true;
            return connectionString;
        }
```

`

This is my method that configure the conection string in my dbContext

`

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.Write);
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn = ConectionStringBuilder();
                optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(conn.ConnectionString);
            }
        }
```

`
I already added the cloud dataBase in the instance

[image]

I already tried with different instances, in different proyects, in the same project and nothing work.

I don't know why.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: the exception message is: Unknown socket error if the database and the container are in the same proyect.

Comment: What's your database engine? And do you have a public IP on your Cloud SQL database?

Comment: I'm using MySql 8.0 and pulic ip on my Sql DataBase

Comment: Hey @FerchoCaxaj, have you solved the issue? We're facing the same problem.